# How to write a html code to show google map

Tags: html, css

I am new to HTML language.I want to add Google Map in my project.

As i am not getting map displayed correctly, and I cannot show my current location that I give in the map

[image: A google map of the UK and Europe]

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overview

Comment: https://mobirise.com/help/how-to-add-google-map-to-website-781.html#:~:text=Go%20to%20maps.google.com,HTML%20code%20of%20the%20map.

Comment: Can you explain about Google Embed because i can't understand it

Comment: and i can't understand API

Comment: There's a step by step guide of how to use the api in the link above. if you can't understand that, then someone trying to explain on here isn't going to be much use as it won't be as detailed.  Instead, have a go, if you get stuck, come back with a specific problem about the code you have tried, why it didn't work and what you are having trouble with

Comment: how to get my Api Key

Comment: click on the link in the top of the left column that says Get an api key

Comment: @SriGnS if you use my link, you don't need an API - I think the API approach is for more experienced developers - the approach in my link contains a step by step explanation which is easy to follow.

Comment: @Shotokan I don't need Mobirise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an API first:

1. Go to the [Google Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/project/_/google/maps-apis/overview)
2. Create or select a project
3. Click continue to enable the API
4. On the credentials page, get an API key.
5. Replace the API key in the code below

HTML:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
       <title>Add Map</title>
     <script
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js? 
         key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap&libraries=&v=weekly"
      defer
    ></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style.css" />
    <script src="./index.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
       <h3>My Google Maps Demo</h3>
       <!--The div element for the map -->
       <div id="map"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

CSS:

```
 /* Set the size of the div element that contains the map */
 #map {
   height: 400px;
   width: 100%;
  }
```

JavaScript:

```
// Initialize and add the map
function initMap() {
  // The location of Uluru
  const uluru = { lat: -25.344, lng: 131.036 };
 // The map, centered at Uluru
  const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: uluru,
  });
 // The marker, positioned at Uluru
   const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: uluru,
    map: map,
  });
  }
```